How to install astro CLI in Windows 11 home, which don't have hyper V?
I am following https://academy.astronomer.io/path/airflow-101 course and it asks to enable windows hyper v to install astro CLI which is not possible in Windows 11 home. Can anyone please suggest a workaround?
I tried enabling hyper V in Windows 11 home. But it is available only in Pro/Enterprise versions
